# DelegateClass vs Class Inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, delegation

Can someone please provide some insight as to when to use delegation via [`DelegateClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-DelegateClass) (e.g. `Seller < DelegateClass(Person)`) and when to use class inheritance (e.g. `Seller < Person`) in ruby?

```
class Seller < DelegateClass(Person)
  def sales
     ...
  end 
end 

class Seller < Person 
  def sales
     ...
  end 
end
```

*When I was looking over the Ruby on Rails source on Github I found quite a few [uses of `DelegateClass`](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DelegateClass).*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple of differences that can help provide insight as to which approach to use.

**1) You can safely delegate to primitives (e.g. String), but cannot always safely inherit from them**

If you're building on top of `Hash` or `String` or `Fixnum`, you're safer using `DelegateClass` (or another delegator). For more on why, [Steve Klabnik's cautioning](https://steveklabnik.com/writing/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes) is a good place to start).

**2) DelegateClass makes it easy to “convert” a more general object into a more specific one**

This makes it easier to accept an instance of a general object and make it behave in a way that's specific to your implementation:

```
class Message < DelegateClass(String)
  def print
    upcase
  end
end

# […]

def log(message)
  message = Message.new(message) unless message.is_a?(Message)
end
```

**3) A gotcha: `DelegateClass` subclasses expect an instance of the delegated class as an argument to `new`**

This can make it tricky to “subclass” classes that you're handing to library code. For example, this is a fairly common practice that won't work out of the box with `DelegateClass`:

```
class MyLogger < DelegateClass(ActiveSupport::Logger); end

Foo::ThirdParty::Library.configure do |c|
  c.logger = MyLogger # no good
end
```

This doesn't work because our library expects to behave like most loggers and instantiate without arguments. This can be addressed by defining `initialize` and creating an instance of `ActiveSupport::Logger`, but probably not the right solution in this case.

Answer (score 5):

delegates model different behaviors of `Person` based on the context. e.g. the same person could be a seller in one context or a buyer in a different context. Inheritance is more rigid: a `Bear` and `Tiger` inherit from `Animal`, but an instance of `Animal` would never need to sometimes behave like a `Bear` and sometimes behave like a `Tiger`. An instance of a descendent of `Animal` is either one or the other.